show counter for nested loop using alphine js
I am trying to add the counter based on the provider. It should be global not service wise. I mean if there are 2 services and both of them have 2 providers, then it should show the counter like provider 1 and 2 for first service, then provider 3 and 4 for next service.
<template x-if="services !== undefined" x-for="(service,key) in services.services">

    <template x-if="service !== undefined">
    
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3 x-text="service.service_name"></h3>
                    <div id="service-info" class="mt-3">
                        <span class="text-left"
                            x-html="'Booking No. '+service.booking_number "></span><br>
                        <span class="text-left" x-html="'Start Time: '+ service.start_time "></span><br>
                        <span class="text-left" x-html="'End Time: '+ service.end_time "></span><br>
                        <span class="text-left"
                            x-html="'Providers: '+ service.providers.length "></span><br>


                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <template x-for="(provider,index) in service.providers" :key="index">
            
                <tr x-show="provider !== undefined && provider.check_in_status !== null">
                    <td>

                        <h3 x-show="details.hide_providers !== undefined && !details.hide_providers"
                            x-text="provider.user.name"></h3>
                        <h3 x-show="details.hide_providers !== undefined && details.hide_providers"
                            x-text="'service-' + service.id + '-' + provider.id + 'Provider ' + providerCounter++"
                            :id="'service-' + service.id + '-' + provider.id"></h3>

                        <!-- Increment customCounter after each provider is rendered -->

                        <div id="provider-info" class="mt-3">
                            <span class="text-left"
                                x-html="'Start Time: '+ new Date(provider.check_in_procedure_values.actual_start_timestamp).toLocaleDateString() "></span><br>
                            <span class="text-left"
                                x-html="'End Time: '+  new Date(provider.check_out_procedure_values.actual_end_timestamp).toLocaleDateString() "></span><br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <div x-show=" 'total_durations_billing' in provider.billing_details ">
                            <span
                                x-show="!provider.service_payment_details.fixed_rate && provider.service_payment_details.day_rate "
                                class="text-left"
                                x-html="provider.billing_details.total_durations_billing.days == null ? '' : provider.billing_details.total_durations_billing.days+' Days '"></span>
                            <span x-show="!provider.service_payment_details.fixed_rate"
                                class="text-left"
                                x-html="provider.billing_details.total_durations_billing.hours == null ? '' : provider.billing_details.total_durations_billing.hours+' Hours '"></span>
                            <span
                                x-show="!provider.service_payment_details.fixed_rate && !provider.service_payment_details.day_rate"
                                class="text-left"
                                x-html="provider.billing_details.total_durations_billing.mins == null ? '' : provider.billing_details.total_durations_billing.mins+' Mins '"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div x-show=" 'total_durations_billing' in provider.billing_details == false ">
                            <span
                                x-show="!provider.service_payment_details.fixed_rate && provider.service_payment_details.day_rate "
                                class="text-left"
                                x-html="service.days == null ? '' : service.days+' Days '"></span>
                            <span x-show="!provider.service_payment_details.fixed_rate"
                                class="text-left"
                                x-html="service.hours == null ? '' : service.hours+' Hours '"></span>
                            <span
                                x-show="!provider.service_payment_details.fixed_rate && !provider.service_payment_details.day_rate"
                                class="text-left"
                                x-html="service.mins == null ? '' : service.mins+' Mins '"></span>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <template x-if="provider.billing_details !== undefined"
                            x-for="(charge,charge_index) in provider.billing_details"
                            :key="charge_index">
                            <template x-if="charge_index == 'service_charges'">

                                <div id="service-list" class="d-flex"
                                    style="justify-content: space-between;">
                                    <div class="text-left mb-2">
                                        <p x-html="'Service Charges'"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-right mb-3">
                                        <p x-html="charge"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </template>
                        </template>


                        <template x-if="provider.billing_details !== undefined"
                            x-for="(charge,charge_index) in provider.billing_details"
                            :key="charge_index">
                            <template
                                x-if="charge_index == 'additional_charges' || charge_index == 'specialization_charges' || charge_index == 'expedited_charges'">
                                <template x-for="(details,detail_index) in charge">
                                    <div id="service-list" class="d-flex"
                                        style="justify-content: space-between;">
                                        <div class="text-left mb-2">
                                            <p x-text="details.label"></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text-right mb-3">
                                            <p x-text="details.charges"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </template>

                            </template>
                        </template>

                        <template x-if="provider.service_payment_details.expedited_rate !== undefined">
                            <div id="service-list" class="d-flex"
                                style="justify-content: space-between;">
                                <div class="text-left mb-2">
                                    <p>Expedition Charges</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-right mb-3">
                                    <p x-html="provider.service_payment_details.expedited_rate"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </template>

                        <template x-if="provider.billing_details !== undefined"
                            x-for="(charge,charge_index) in provider.billing_details"
                            :key="charge_index">
                            <template x-if="charge_index == 'discounts_list'">
                                <template x-for="(discounts,discount_index) in charge"
                                    :key="discount_index">
                                    <template x-if="discount_index !== undefined">
                                        <div id="service-list" class="d-flex"
                                            style="justify-content: space-between;">
                                            <div class="text-left mb-2">
                                                <p
                                                    x-html="'<strong>Discount :</strong> ' + discounts.label">
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="text-right mb-3">
                                                <p x-html="discounts.value"></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </template>
                                </template>
                            </template>
                        </template>

                        <div id="service-list" class="d-flex" style="justify-content: space-between;">
                            <div class="text-left mb-2">
                                <p><strong>Total Provider Charges</strong></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-right mb-3">
                                <p
                                    x-html="services.currency + provider.billing_details.total_provider_charges">
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Increment the counter after rendering each service -->
            </template>

I tried adding the counter but it was always returning the max count for every provider, meaning that if I had 10 providers it was showing provider 10 for each of them. Any ideas how I solve this?

Please click [edit], then click the button marked [<>] and provide a [mcve] with relevant HTML, Script and frameworks from CDN, while you are at it, format the templates nicely with two spaces indentation

If the variable providerCounter is a global variable then yes, it will display the same value everywhere you use it. It seems like you need a numeric index for each provider. If the provider.id is not sufficient for your needs then you can add a new variable for each provider object and set it before Alpine renders the content. Preferably in the alpine:init event like this:
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    // init data before alpine starts
})

For us to really give you a good answer you need to explain the significance of this counter. What is it for?
